# How to display multiple TextViews in a RecyclerView list item

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm using a ReyclerView and I want to display 3 TextViews in each list item.
so far I managed to display 3 TextViews but as 3 different list items.

Here's my adapter code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_item);
        }
    }

    public CustomAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

And layout_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Simply put 3 `TextView`s in your `layout_item`?

Answer (score 1):

just add two more textViews in layout_item

Comment: what happens when you do so

Comment: what exactly you want, more textView in the recycler or in the holder

Comment: hard to explain
its just not working the way I wanted

Comment: more textViews in the holder in think

Answer (score 1):

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

// If you want your textviews next to each other use  android:orientation="horizontal" in LinearLayout or if you want your textviews one below the other use  android:orientation="vertical" and this will in one view

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout instead of Linear layout if you want to set three Textviews .It will be much easier you can drag and drop textview from design Platte where you want to set those Textviews